# Get parallel edges and give them color

Tags: cytoscape.js

I want to get list of all parallel edges within a collection and give them seperate color

My code is

```
cy.elements().parallelEdges().animate({ 'style':{'line-color':'coral', 'width': '10px'} }, {duration: 1000 })
```

But it end up in coloring all edges....

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You call the function on all elements in cytoscape, the documentation implys, that you have to callthe function on edges.

```
cy.edges().parallelEdges().animate();
```

Edit:
cy.edges() wont work, the funciton is designed to give you the parallel edges to a set collection of edges, so if you want to achieve this, I think you have to:

- Iterate through all nodes via cy.nodes() and a for loop
- Get the edges of the current node with cy.edges("[source = theRightId]")
- Check for every edge (Just one edge for the following function!!) if it has a parallel edge via cy.$('#idOfEdge').parallelEdges()
- Put those with a parallel edge in a cy.collection() [add elements in a collection with: yourCollection = yourCollection.add(theParallelEdges)]

Comment: I tried this... but it changes all edges.... 
i want to target only paralleledges alone....

is there any other idea,,,

Comment: Technically you could iterate throug every npde in cytoscape, get the nodes targets and check if the node and the current target have parallel edges.  If that is true, add it to a collection and call the animate() on said collection

Comment: I edited my answer, when you follow the instructions, maybe you will find the answer

Comment: So? How did it go?

Comment: Sorry for late reply bro... I achieved that by another method... But
will gave your method a try.... and will share both ideas to achieve it...